# PostGIS Unknown colormap keyword

Tags: postgis, thematic-map

I'm working with thematic maps with ST_ColorMap function smoothly until I try to create my own thematic map(colormap).

```
WITH
 canvas AS (
        SELECT ST_Raster(
                ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(geom), 4326),
                800,
                (800 * (SELECT (Max(ST_YMax(geom)) - Min(ST_YMin(geom))) / (Max(ST_XMax(geom)) - Min(ST_XMin(geom)))))::integer,
                '32BF', 0, 0) AS rast
          FROM estado
           )
SELECT ST_AsPNG(
        ST_ColorMap(
         ST_Union(ST_AsRaster(geom, canvas.rast, '32BF'::text, aland, 0)),'
                 100% 255   0   0
                  80% 160   0   0
                  50% 130   0   0
                  30%  30   0   0
                  20%  60   0   0
                   0%   0   0   0
                   nv 255 255 255
                  ')) AS rast
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Unknown colormap keyword: 
100% 255   0   0
 80% 160   0   0
 50% 130   0   0
 30%  30   0   0
 20%  60   0   0
  0%   0   0   0
  nv 255 255 255
```

I tried the first example in the documentation for PostGIS:
[ST_ColorMap](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/RT_ST_ColorMap.html), and I get the same error.
Only works fine with pre-defined colormap keywords.

Any ideas?

**PostgreSQL version:** "PostgreSQL 9.3.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit"

**PostGIS version:** "POSTGIS="2.1.3 r12547" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3924" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.0, released 2013/04/24" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER"

Comment: You will need to add a bit more information, such as the query you are running.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the line break after the opening apostrophe. :$

Comment: I can't believe this is the right answer